# Why doesn't this track by work in AngularJS (Angular 1.X)?

Tags: angularjs

I am setting the `ng-model` to a value in the controller.

I expect the dropdown to sync (two-way bind?) to the value in the controller.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.model = 'b'
  $scope.model2 = 'b'
  $scope.items = [{
    'n': 'a'
  }, {
    'n': 'b'
  }]
}
```

```css
.done-true {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <select ng-model="model" ng-options="f.n as f.n for f in items"></select>
    <select ng-model="model2" ng-options="f.n as f.n for f in items track by f.n"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works:

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-options="f.n as f.n for f in items"></select>
```

This does not:

```
<select ng-model="model2" ng-options="f.n as f.n for f in items track by f.n"></select>
```

The `track by` seems to be the problem.

What do I have to do to get `track by` to work?

Comment: if you change a model , it will work vice versa: http://plnkr.co/edit/sfhDV8oVNyRXU1YJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model doesn't contain the variable "n" that you're trying to track. Change it to $scope.model2 = { n: 'b' }.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is pretty tricky `ng-options`  with `track by`.

However, if you define a model not as string:

```
$scope.model = 'b'
$scope.model2 = 'b'
```

but as object:

```
$scope.model = {'n': 'b'};
$scope.model2 = {'n': 'b'};
```

it can work but with some changes, notice `ng-model="model.n"`:

```
<select ng-model="model.n" 
  ng-options="f.n as f.n for f in items">
</select>


<select ng-model="model2" 
  ng-options="f as f.n for f in items track by f.n">
</select>
```

<kbd>[Demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bWZCC7jhNrDF8KMA)</kbd>